# Sharing Rails session with other apps using DB Session Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, session-storage

**Devise** gem is used for authentication.

Rails sessions are stored **in database**.

In order to use sessions outside of Rails 3, I created a model called `Session`. Added `user_id` column to the `sessions` table.

When user signs in, I should update `user_id` column in sessions table. So in `ApplicationController` I added a method:

```
  protected
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    @session = Session.find_by_session_id(request.session_options[:id])
    @session.update_attribute(:user_id, current_user.id)
    stored_location_for(resource) || root_path if @session.save
  end
```

But just after redirect, the recent `session` gets destroyed and I end up with another session in DB with a blank `user_id`.

What's the best method to write `user_id` once on successful login?

Answer (score 1):

José Valim (of Devise) answered:

> Since Rails 3.1, Warden sets the :renew option when an user signs in, forcing the old session to be destroyed and creating a new one.

So what I ended up doing is creating `update_session` filter in `ApplicationController`.

```
  before_filter :update_session

  protected
  def update_session
    if user_signed_in?
      @session = Session.find_by_session_id(request.session_options[:id])
      @session.update_attribute(:user_id, current_user.id)
    end
  end
```

Since Rails caches DB queries there will be no actual SQL call to get session from the `sessions` table. It's already in memory. The same is true for updates. Rails will only update `user_id` the first time. All other times `UPDATE` query won't go to DBMS.

Comment: btw, there's no need to use an instance variable for `@session`.